# Trigger YUI onDOMReady programatically after comepletion of turbolinks page:load event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, yui, turbolinks

I am trying to implement turbolinks in my rails app, its an old app which has pretty huge codebase.

We use YUI and Jquery in our app. 
Now after integrating turbolinks in the app, the Dom ready event would not be triggered as per the turbolinks behavior.

Changing every place which calls YUI.util.event.onDOMReady is not a good option. I want to be  able to trigger YUI's ready event on 'page:load' event

**QUESTION**

How do I trigger YUI's onDOMReady event after turbolinks 'page:load'

PS: Because of Turbolinks implementation page does not reload, it just replaces the content of body tag with the body tag in response somewhat like PJAX

Any help is highly apprciated

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery.ready();`?

Comment: Yes, that part is done. I want the YUI part triggering onDOMReady

Comment: What about replacing the onDOMReady function itself right after YUI loads and doing whatever you like with the registered listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do :

```
Y._yuievt.events.domready.fired = false;
Y._yuievt.events.domready.fire();
```

You have to reset fired value of domready, because it's considered as single execution event.